# Force Match phrase to discard results with full email searching only its domain

Tags: elasticsearch, match, amazon-opensearch, elasticsearch-analyzers, match-phrase

I'd like to find in my ElasticSearch index the string `outlook.com` inside a text with a `match_phrase` query. **But I don't want results that are** `something...@outlook.com`, that are taken with this query:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [],
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": {
              "query": "outlook.com",
              "slop": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I think that these results are taken because the tokenizer of the standard analyzer separate `something...@outlook.com` in `[something...],[outlook.com]` with `@` as separator.

I tried to put the analyzer `whitespace` to tokenize as `[something...@outlook.com]` and avoid taking the full emails as results. But with this query:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [],
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": {
              "query": "outlook.com",
              "slop": 0,
              "analyzer": "whitespace",
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

still finds results like `something...@outlook.com`. How can I do?

**UPDATE:**

In my mapping, I set `standard` analyzer a time ago. So my intuition is that even if I use a `whitespace` analyzer at search time, the documents are already tokenized with the `standard` one, so the tokenization is no more changeable after the indexing time.

I tried doing a `painless script` to match a certain pattern, but my field is type `text` so the search takes too much time.

Otherwise, a `regexp` query can do something similar:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [],
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "message": ".*[^A-Za-z0-9\\@]outlook.com[^A-Za-z0-9\\@].*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But unfortunately reading `regexp` [syntax documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html) there is a limited set of operators. For example with this regex `[^A-Za-z0-9\\@]` I mean any characters, but not a `@` before `outlook.com` and
not an alphanumeric character (this is to simulate the word boundary that we could have with the `match_phrase` query). My problem is that if the field starts or ends with `Outlook.com`, it's not retrieved because the regex doesn't find a character before or after (`[^A-Za-z0-9\\@]` doesn't match the empty string).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `regexp` query instead of `match_phrase` like this:

```
{  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "message": ".*[^@]outlook.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried with the `regexp` too. Anyway I wanted the same "effect" of match_phrase: so I think before and after `outlook.com` should be something like word boundaries except `@`. Some of the typical regex patterns are not available in the ES syntax (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html) so it was hard for me to create such a similar pattern. Moreover don't I have to escape `@`? Like `...[^\\@]..`. Anyway I don't understand why the `match_phrase` doesn't search the exact token, but it finds also results that "contains" that string.

Comment: Understood: the analyzer expressed in search time is only applied to the text you put in the query but not in the text that was already indexed in the documents (they were analyzed with the standard analyzer)